# How to change slider-thumb color using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

This is my actual input range:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

And [this is my code](https://codepen.io/mistochi/pen/YMQZKV).

**RangeComponent.tsx**:

```
const active = '#64c3ef'
const inactive = '#dbdbdb'

export class RangeComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  inputRef: any = React.createRef()

  state = { value: 10 }

  handleChange = (min: number, max: number) => (event: any) => {
    const value = event.target.value
    const progress = (value / max) * 100 + '%'
    this.setState({ value: value })
    const newBackgroundStyle = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${active} 0% ${progress}%, ${inactive} ${progress}% 100%)`
    this.inputRef.current.style.background = newBackgroundStyle
  }

  render() {
    const minValue = 10 
    const maxValue = 300
    const progress = (this.state.value / maxValue) * 100 + '%'

    const styleInput = {
      background: `linear-gradient(90deg, ${active} 0% ${progress}%, ${inactive} ${progress}% 100%)`,
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          ref={this.inputRef}
          id="sliderId"
          className="inputR"
          name="sliderName"
          type="range"
          min={minValue}
          max={maxValue}
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange(minValue, maxValue)}
          style={styleInput}
        />
        <div className="label">
          {this.state.value}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**style.css**:

```
.inputR::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75);
}
```

If possible, I would like to control the thumb color not in style.css but in RangeComponent.tsx.

I don't understand why the class `inputR` has no effects on the input style.
How can I change the style using CSS from javascript object (`styleInput`)?

Comment: Could you possibly upload to github or codepen and we can have a look? Please also include the css for the "slider" class.

Comment: @Francois Sure! I added a Codepen link: https://codepen.io/mistochi/pen/YMQZKV

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I'm currently on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

So to answer your last question first: "why the class inputR has no effects on the input style."

The first part is that in order to style the slider / thumb you need to set the "appearance: none". Remember to add the -webkit-appearance for cross-browser support. This will effectively turn the slider / thumb invisible for you to style over. Do this for both inputR and inputR::-webkit-slider-thumb. ([See codepen solution](https://codepen.io/francoisgeyser/pen/eoydWj))

The second part is that while you can do `.inputR {-webkit-appearance: none}`

in CSS or 

`const styleInput = {
                    WebkitAppearance: 'none'
                    }`

in JSX,
you cannot do pseudo-classes in JSX, eg. `.inputR::-webkit-slider-thumb {}` . Which you need to do in order to style the thumb.

My proposal is that you set up the basic styling for the slider / thumb in CSS and then do the dynamic part via inline styling or as a style object.([See codepen solution](https://codepen.io/francoisgeyser/pen/eoydWj))

The next thing you will have to look at is your linear gradient. you are using the variable **progress** and adding a "%" sign.
`const styleInput = {
      background:`linear-gradient(90deg, ${active} 0% ${progress}%, ${inactive} ${progress}% 100%)`,
    }`

But in your code you already add the "%" into **progress**. 
`const progress = (value / max) * 100 + '%'`
So the string literal resolves to 100%% and your gradient does not render. I removed the "%" from the style object ([See codepen solution](https://codepen.io/francoisgeyser/pen/eoydWj))

I hope that helps, let me know if anything is unclear.